# jQuery gallery is repeating first image for one rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, slideshow

The gallery loads the first image, then switches to the next, switches back to the first, then to the thrird, and so on. Not sure why, this is happening.

jQuery:

```
var hoverhome = 'url("images/HomePreview.png")';
  var hoverhome = 'url("images/HomePreview.png")';
  var hoverhome = 'url("images/HomePreview.png")';
  var hovergallery = 'url("images/GalleryPreview.png")';
  var hoverhome = 'url("images/HomePreview.png")';
  var empty = 'none';
  var success = 'SUCCESS!';
  //home
  jQuery('nav .home a').hover(function()
  {
    jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', hoverhome);

  });
  jQuery('nav .home a').mouseout(function()
  {    
        jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', empty);
  }); 
  //about
  jQuery('nav .home a').hover(function()
  {
    jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', hoverhome);

  });
  jQuery('nav .home a').mouseout(function()
  {    
        jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', empty);
  }); 
  //services
  jQuery('nav .home a').hover(function()
  {
    jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', hoverhome);

  });
  jQuery('nav .home a').mouseout(function()
  {    
        jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', empty);
  }); 
  //gallery
  jQuery('nav .gallery a').hover(function()
  {
    jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', hovergallery);

  });
  jQuery('nav .home a').mouseout(function()
  {    
        jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', empty);
  }); 
  //contact us
  jQuery('nav .home a').hover(function()
  {
    jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', hoverhome);

  });
  jQuery('nav .home a').mouseout(function()
  {    
        jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', empty);
  }); 


$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(1000)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

Call in the php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery('#slideshow > div:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function() { 
jQuery('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(1000)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
 //--><!]]></script>


<div id="slideshow">
<div id="slideshow1">
```

I then call the images from css as the backgrounds of the various divs, they load fine. As a matter of fact, the entire slideshow works fine except for the glitch of showing the first slide multiple times during the first rotation, after the first rotation it works fine. The site is up at www.bingetech.com for further reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML of slideshow,

Only keep the 1st slideshow as display:block and rest of as display:none

```
<div style="display: block; opacity: 0;" id="slideshow5">
</div><div style="display: none;" id="slideshow1">
</div><div style="display: none;" id="slideshow2">
</div><div style="display: none;" id="slideshow3">
</div><div style="display: none" id="slideshow4">
</div>
```